# How to change default style of React Phone Number input field

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-hook-form

How can I override the style of the react-phone-number-input component using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input?

Along with this component, I'm using a React Hook Form and Tailwind CSS. Unfortunately, the background and border colors do not change, and the border width is too wide. I'm not sure how I can change the style.

[image: Field Image]

```
    //React hook form
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        watch,
        formState: { errors },
        control,
      } = useForm();


    //Component
    <PhoneInputWithCountry
      international
      name="phone"
      control={control}
      defaultCountry="BD"
      country="BD"
      id="phone"
      className="rounded rounded-full bg-gray-100 py-1 px-2 text-gray-700 shadow-sm border-green"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set classes. Because component styles override them. You can set the `style` prop like this. And make sure to import component styles as well. `import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'`

```
<PhoneInputWithCountry
   style={{borderRadius: 3px, ...}}
   ...
/>
```

Comment: As you can see, it only affects the input component's outer side, not its inner side.
SS Link : https://i.imgur.com/go7oh7d.png
Code SS Link: https://i.imgur.com/ICY79yU.png

Comment: You can view the classes by inspecting the element. And write custom css for that class

Comment: @Maneth It still affects the whole component not the inner input component. Can you please show example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Found this while trying to solve the same problem myself and figured I'd put this here for anyone else coming from Google.

I am using the [PhoneInputWithCountry](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input#react-hook-form) from 'react-phone-number-input/react-hook-form' and Tailwind. The easiest way I found to style the input itself was by passing some Tailwind classes to the numberInputProps as below.

```
<PhoneInputWithCountry
  name="phone" // whatever your name for react-hook-form is
  control={control} // from react-hook-form
  numberInputProps={{
    className: 'rounded-md px-4 focus:outline-none...' // my Tailwind classes
  }}
/>
```

Exact documentation [here](https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/react-phone-number-input/docs/index.html#phoneinputwithcountry:%7E:text=focuses%20or%20blurs.-,numberInputProps,-object), as well as explanations of all of the other props the input will accept. I found this much easier than providing my own custom input. Hopefully this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem so I injected the tailwind css inside the inputProps and it worked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLSCV.png)

```js
<div>
  <label htmlFor="phone" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Phone Number: 
     <PhoneInput 
        id="phone" 
        name="phone" 
        country={'us'}
        value={phoneNumber} 
        onChange={handleChange}
        inputProps={{
            required:true,
            className:"bg-opacity-50 text-gray-950 mt-2 block border rounded-md border-gray-700 h-[48px] w-[450px] pl-[45px] pr-[12px] justify-between shadow-sm focus:border-gray-300 focus:ring focus:ring-gray-200"
}}
                                    
/>
</label>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).